# Swift: Scroll view with image view isn't enabled?

Tags: swift

So I created a scroll view and put an image view in it. I initialized the scroll view as a variable and wrote the following code in my ViewController and yet, the image won't scroll. 
What's wrong?

Later on I'm also going to need to put several buttons into this scroll view so if I'm missing something here, it'd be great if you could address it for buttons as well.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ScrollView.scrollEnabled = true

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: what are the frames of the scroll view and imageview respectively?

Comment: @user1840001 as in their sizes?

Comment: The content is bigger than the ScrollView- the scroll view is 320 by 98 and the content is 473 by 115

Comment: try explicitly setting the content size like so:         self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:somethingBigger, height: somethingBigger);

Comment: Awesome, its scrolling now. I only want it to scroll horizontally tho and I can move the content vertically. I only have the horizontal scroll bar box checked in the story board. How can I make it only scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the content size like so:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:somethingBigger, height: somethingBigger);
```

To answer your follow-up question...Make height of the scrollView equal to that of the screen.  Then it won't scroll vertically.  Programmatic stuff overwrites storyboard stuff.

Comment: Got it. Also.. Do you have any idea why the scroll would work differently on my iPhone? It all works perfectly in the simulator but on my device the content bounces back too quickly and the user can't even see the content they just scrolled to.

Comment: The solution for what you just described would be to increase the width of the content size.  Are you sure your iPhone screen size and simulator screen size are the same?  That's the only reason I can think that the behaviors wouldn't match.

Comment: Yes they are both 5s. Ok so you are saying if I had a longer image it will bounce but not so that it is back to the original position right

Comment: Ok that wasn't the problem. It seems like I am able to see the end of the content, I can scroll to it, but on the device it just wants to bounce back immediately whereas it stays in that place on the simulator